# Need to find out what part is called

Tags: transmission

I own a 2006 dodge sprinter and cannot figure out what the part connected to the transmission with the wheel is!

I want to buy a new one and have spent countless time trying to find out what part it is. I hope somebody can help me.

[image: Gearbox]

[image: Close-up of drive end of gearbox]

Comment: That component is called a drive shaft.  It runs back to the differential where the rear axle is and powers the wheels.

Answer (score 14):

It's not too clear which part you're referring to, so I've annotated your image with the most likely items.

[image]